# Adding a running total calculator with javascript for a website

Tags: javascript, html

I am needing to create a calculator in javascript for a website that is wanting to display a total number of items distributed (similar to Apple's iTunes download promotions). The math for the calculation part is easy, it's a whole number approximately every 6 hours, I just am having difficulty making some existing javascripts work because they reset every time the user refreshes the browser page.

What is the best way to keep a running total in javascript?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You're missing an ingredient: time. Just add the current time/date into your formula?

Comment: Okay... so can I use a starting number, then add the "calculation" on top of that using time/date?

Comment: Something like `x = scale * (currentTime - startTime)`.

Comment: Okay... I think I can work with that, thank you so much Marty, you rock!

Comment: [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/UNG3z/)